# Public Property has multiple definitions with identical signatures

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sdk, dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing an application to transfer data between an in-house web application and a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 instance. I generated early bound entity classes using the CrmSvcUtil included with the Dynamics CRM SDK with the following parameters:

> crmsvcutil /l:vb /url:http://nameofserver/MicrosoftDynamics/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:myorganizationcrmsdktypes.vb /username:username /password:password /domain:domain

I then renamed the existing standard sdk output file in my project and added the file generated by using the above command. Then I built the project and began receiving numerous errors like so:

> Public Property account_activity_parties As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ActivityParty)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out...and I'll post the solution here just in case anyone else runs into it. I renamed my original early bound entity class myorganizationcrmsdktypes-old.vb and left it in the project. Apparently the project was building from both files, and this was causing the duplication.